# 404 page when running project through eclipse on Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, struts2

Using Struts2 , I have set up a very simplistic webapp but when i run it in eclipese i got 404 error.. here is my all codes and jarfiles

**URL :** localhost:8985/firststruts/index.jsp

**Jar files**

1. commons-fileupload-1.3.1
2. commons-io-2.2
3. commons-lang-2.4
4. commons-logging-1.1.3
5. commons-logging-api-1.1
6. freemarker-2.3.19
7. javassist-3.11.0.GA
8. ognl-3.0.6
9. struts2-core-2.3.16.3
10. xwork-core-2.3.16.3

**Struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts  
Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">  
<struts>  
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">  

<action name="Product" class="com.javatpoint.Product">  
<result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>  
</action>  

</package>  
</struts>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<display-name>firstjsp</display-name>
<filter>  
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>  
<filter-class>  
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter  
</filter-class>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>  
<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**product.java**

```
    public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float price;
    public int getId() {
    return id;
    }   
    public void setId(int id) {
     this.id = id;
    }


   public String getName() {
    return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
   }

   public float getPrice() {
    return price;
   }

   public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
   }

   public String execute() {
    return "success";
   }
   }
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  

Product Id:<s:property value="id"/><br/>  
Product Name:<s:property value="name"/><br/>  
Product Price:<s:property value="price"/><br/>
```

**index.java**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  
<s:form action="product">  
<s:textfield name="id" label="Product Id"></s:textfield>  
<s:textfield name="name" label="Product Name"></s:textfield>  
<s:textfield name="price" label="Product Price"></s:textfield>  
<s:submit value="save"></s:submit>  
</s:form>
```

im new to struts2 so please help me to solve this.

Comment: post your stacktraces and also the `url` you are accessing in the browser

Comment: here is the url http://localhost:8985/firststruts/

Comment: @Kanishkagunarathna You should do it by editing your question. Nobody can read this url.

Comment: oh okay i will edit my post agan

Comment: i sort it out guys i added few more jar files now it worked  

these are the jar fles

asm-3.3
asm-commons-3.3
asm-tree-3.3
struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.15.1

now it worked properly

this is a vdo tuturial for it

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyfOGS_rfWU8kKPqORg8lEw